# Symfony query into friendly Url

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am trying to make a stock control app using Symfony 3.1.1 from a similar app.

The customer wants that all the url have this pattern

domain/suppliers/2

(where 2 is the id of the supplier in the database)

At the moment, the url I am obtaining is something like

domain/supplier?id=2

I have been looking through documentation of the old project, symfony page and here, but I can't understand how can I routing, as the project is a fork of another one I am constrained to keep as much code as I can.

All the code extends from a Bundle, so for make a list it is calling this function (I am not overwritten or adding anything to the SupllierController at the moment):

```
     * @Route("")
 */
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    $list = $this->createList($this->getListObject());
    $list->handleRequest($request)->process();
    $list->setTemplatesScope($this->getTemplatesScope() . ':Listing\\');

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonResponse($list->getInfo());
    } else {
        return $this->render($this->getTemplatesScope().':list.html.twig', $list->render());
    }
}
```

The list that is called by the controller is very simple, all my changes are related with the creation of a button where I try to take de id of the suplier:

```
 <a href="{{ path('app_supplierproduct_list', { id : row.id }) }}" class="btn btn-default">
            Productos
        </a>
```

The SupplierProductList (that I am trying to call) is:

```
public function buildList(ListBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setEntity('AppBundle:SupplierProduct')
            ->setMode('normal', 'modal')
            ->addField('products', 'entity', [
                'label'             => 'Producto',
                'class'             => 'AppBundle:Product',
                'choice_label'      => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->orderBy('e.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ])
            ->addField('supplier', 'entity', [
                'label'             => 'Proveedor',
                'class'             => 'AppBundle:Supplier',
                'choice_label'      => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->orderBy('e.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ])      
            ->addField('name', 'text', [
                'label'             => 'Nombre en el Proveedor',
            ])
            ->addField('code', 'text', [
                'label'             =>  'Código en el Proveedor',
            ])
            ->addFilter('name', 'text', [
                'label'             => 'Nombre en el proveedor',
            ])
            ->addFilter('sku', 'text', [
                'label'            =>   'Código interno del proveedor'
            ])
            ->addFilter('updatedAt', 'date', [
                'label'             => 'Última Modificación'
            ])            
            ->addFilter('supplier', 'entity', [
                'label'             => 'Proveedor',
                'class'             => 'AppBundle:Supplier',
                'choice_label'      => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->orderBy('e.name', 'ASC');
                },

            ])
            ->addFilter('customer', 'entity', [
                'label'             => 'Cliente',
                'class'             => 'AppBundle:Customer',
                'choice_label'      => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->orderBy('e.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'list_supplierproduct';
    }
```

routing file:

```
app_supplier_customer:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/SupplierCustomerController.php"
    type:     annotation

app_supplier_customer:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/SupplierCustomerController.php"
    type:     annotation

app_supplier_customer:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/SupplierCustomerController.php"
    type:     annotation

app_supplier_product:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/SupplierProductController.php"
    type:     annotation

app_supplier_customer:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/SupplierCustomerController.php"
    type:     annotation

app_sale:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/SaleController.php"
    type:     annotation

app_product:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/ProductController.php"
    type:     annotation

app_group:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/GroupController.php"
    type:     annotation

app_customer:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/CustomerController.php"
    type:     annotation

app_brand:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/BrandController.php"
    type:     annotation

odin_form_filemanager:
     path:  /filemanager/
     defaults: { _controller: OdinFormBundle:FileManager:show }

odin_panel:
    resource:       '@OdinPanelBundle/Controller'


odin_panel_login_check:
    path:           /login/check


odin_panel_logout:
    path:           /logout
    app:
        resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
        type:     annotation
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: added code as requested

Comment: can you share your `route` code as well, right now it says `@Route("")` what does the actual route looks like?

Comment: `route` file added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completing for documentation purposes:

Finally I realized that the Controller Action doesn't receive the id as parameter in the annotation block.